# Fail to load javascript template file using requireJS

Tags: requirejs

The following code does not work:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'lodash',
  'backbone',
  'mustache',
  'text!/app/js/templates/TreeCombo/TreeCombo.html' //Is this right?
  ], function($, _, Backbone, Mustache, MyTemplate){
 ...
})
```

I've got the following error messages in the console:

```
GET http://localhost:8888/app/js/text.js 404 (File not found)
```

It seems the requireJS is not recognizing the "text!" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the ["text" plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text) within your project (and set up the path to it in the `require.config` if needed). It is  not bundled in.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to include it? Like other common modules like jquery?

Comment: yeah, exactly the same way as jQuery or any other deps.